# How to get a form's maximized client size without maximizing it?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get the client size of a `Form` when it's maximized without maximize it?

From example, I want to create a `Bitmap` with the same size of the maximized `Form`'s client size, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Screen.FromControl(this).GetWorkingArea();
```

to calculate the size (without taskbar)
then substract the difference between the Forms ClientSize / Size.
Hope that works, haven't tested it.

**Update:**

A bit hacky, but I tried it and it works.

```
        var frm = new Form();
        frm.Opacity = 100;
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        frm.Show();

        while (!frm.IsHandleCreated)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

        var result = frm.ClientSize;
        frm.Close();
        return result;
```

**Update2:**

This is a nicer solution.
I disable painting of the Form, maximize it, get the client area, set it back to normal and return the result. Works well, without flicker or something.

```
    private static Size GetMaximizedClientSize(Form form)
    {
        var original = form.WindowState;
        try
        {
            BeginUpdate(form);

            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            return form.ClientSize;

        }
        finally
        {
            form.WindowState = original;   
            EndUpdate(form);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private extern static int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private enum Message : int
    {
        WM_SETREDRAW = 0x000B, // int 11
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls user32.dll SendMessage(handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, null) native function to disable painting
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="c"></param>
    public static void BeginUpdate(Control c)
    {
        SendMessage(c.Handle, (int)Message.WM_SETREDRAW, new IntPtr(0), IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls user32.dll SendMessage(handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, null) native function to enable painting
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="c"></param>
    public static void EndUpdate(Control c)
    {
        SendMessage(c.Handle, (int)Message.WM_SETREDRAW, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Comment: When the Form isn't maximized, there are border size in the Form size, and when the Form is maximized the form's border is disappeared. So this is not correct.

Comment: You are right, I added another solution that creates a hidden form and returns the client size supposing that the value will be the same as your form. You could store the result so you only have to do this once.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following link,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is the better answer.